# Unable to get the output of query

Tags: sql, xml, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is the table:

```
create table companies
(
    id varchar2(40),
    company xmltype 
)
```

`XMLTYPE` column company stored as CLOB;

The output I am trying to get

```
SELECT EXTRACT(company ,'/companies/company[15]/name') 
FROM companies;
```

I was running this query and the output I got this error:

> Error at Command Line : 943 Column : 56
> Error report -
> SQL Error: ORA-00911: invalid character
> 00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
> *Cause:    The identifier name started with an ASCII character other than a letter or a number. After the first character of the identifier name, ASCII characters are allowed including "$", "#" and "_".  Identifiers enclosed in double quotation marks may contain any character other than a double quotation. Alternate quotation marks (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as delimiters. For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language Reference Manual.
> *Action:  Check the Oracle identifier naming convention. If you are attempting to provide a password in the IDENTIFIED BY clause of a CREATE USER or ALTER USER statement, then it is recommended to always enclose the password in double quotation marks because characters other than the double quotation are then allowed.

I was trying to get the data from an xml column that is on index 15.

Comment: My apologies, I accidentally added spoilers in it

Comment: If that is really line 943 from your script, then character 56 is the 'F' in 'FROM'. So.. does you real query have a column alias there that you've omitted from the question? Or do you perhaps have an odd Unicode character that looks like an F? Or an invisible character before the FROM?